# How to implement a broadcast calendar in Kotlin (or Java)

Tags: java, kotlin, calendar

I'm trying to write an application that calculates the week number according to the [broadcast calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_calendar). The Wikipedia definition says:

> Every week in the broadcast calendar starts on a Monday and ends on a Sunday
> [...] the first week of every broadcast month always contains the Gregorian calendar first of the month

So I thought I could use [WeekFields](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) class and tried implementing it this way:

```
    val broadcastCalendar = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 1)
    val march1 = LocalDate.of(2022, 3, 1)
    val weekOfMarch1 = march1.get(broadcastCalendar.weekOfYear())
    println("March 1 2022: $weekOfMarch1") // 10
```

This works fine most of the time but when trying to figure out the week numbers at the end and beginning of the year it fails:

```
    val lastDayOf2022 = LocalDate.of(2022, 12, 31)
    val lastWeekOf2022 = lastDayOf2022.get(broadcastCalendar.weekOfYear())

    val firstDayOf2023 = LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 1)
    val firstWeekOf2023 = firstDayOf2023.get(broadcastCalendar.weekOfYear())

    println("last week of 2022: $lastWeekOf2022") // 53
    println("first week of 2023: $firstWeekOf2023") // 1
```

According to Wikipedia's definition, the last week of 2022 should be 52 (Dec 19 - Dec 25) and the first one in 2023 should be 1 (Dec 26 - Jan 1) - see [here](https://www.rab.com/public/reports/2022-2023.pdf).

How can I use WeekFields (or any other way) to fetch the correct week number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From these quotes in the Wikipedia article, it seems like this calendar system uses a week-based year.

> For example, if January 1 falls on a Saturday, then the broadcast calendar year would begin on the preceding Monday, December 27.

> Broadcast calendar years can have either 52 or 53 weeks.

Because of this is, you should use [`weekOfWeekBasedYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekOfWeekBasedYear()):

```
val broadcastCalendar = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 1)
val lastDayOf2022 = LocalDate.of(2022, 12, 31)
val lastWeekOf2022 = march1.get(broadcastCalendar.weekOfWeekBasedYear())
println(lastWeekOf2022) // 1
```

> This represents the concept of the count of weeks within the year where weeks start on a fixed day-of-week, such as Monday and each week belongs to exactly one year.

Comment: Great, thanks. Actually came to the same conclusion but you beat me to it :)